# How to check if RDS token is valid

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk

I'm setting up a Java program that gets an RDS token for AWS and uses it to connect to a MySql database hosted on RDS.

This is the code to get the token.

```
        RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
            .credentials(creds)
            .region(region)
            .build();

        String authToken = generator.getAuthToken(
            GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
            .hostname(hostName)
            .port(Integer.parseInt(port))
            .userName(username)
            .build());
```

The problem is this always generates a token even if the IAM user doesn't have permission to access that resource or if the user or the hostName or username are invalid or don't exist.

This leads to a MySql error when trying to access the database. Usually it throws this exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username' (using password: YES)
```

I'd like to throw and pass up a more appropriate and descriptive exception. Is there a way to test if the RDS token is valid before trying to connect to the database? If so can you get the reason it is invalid? (i.e. user doesn't have correct permissions or resource doesn't exist)

Alternatively, a way to throw an exception before it generates an invalid token would also be acceptable.